# Getting text after a match from stdout

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I want to extract the next word/number after specific words I find using grep or whatnot.

As an example lets say this is what I have in stdout

```
string-a0 match-a1 string-a2 string-a3
string-b0 string-b1 match-b2 string-b3
match-c0 string-c1 string-c2 string-c3
```

I want to be left with just this

```
string-a2
string-b3
string-c1
```

mind that `match-a1 != match-b2 != match-c0`

EDIT

A concrete example...

stdout is this

```
open 0.23 date ...
close 1.52 date ...
open 2.34 date ...
close 5.92 date ...
open 10.78 date ...
close 24.21 date ...
total 45.3
```

I'm searching for the words `open`, `close` and `total` so the output should be

```
0.23
1.52
2.34
5.92
10.78
24.21
45.3
```

Comment: why string-a2 in line 1 and why not string-a0?

Comment: because I want the **next** string after the match

Comment: Could you elaborate your matching condition? Or a better example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I thought I did... I'll try again

Comment: I don't know bash, but I imagine the regex would be `match-[abc][012] (\S+)` and grab the first capture group.

Comment: @MichelleTan I've added another (concrete) example

Comment: A simple `\b(\d+\.\d+)\b` just grabbing a decimal number? [Check it out here](https://regex101.com/r/gW2aZ4/1).

Comment: `grep -oP '(open|close|total)\s+\K\S+'`

Comment: Are 'open', 'close', 'total' always in first column? From your first example i thoughd that it may vary.

Comment: @Arnial no. Check the generic example

Comment: @123 this is not a duplicate of the question you guys tagged since I have a **set of words** I need to match against where's the other question requires only a single match. It might be trivial for those basking in bash and awk glory but unfortunately I'm not there yet.

Comment: @YoniLevy I did not vote to close as duplicate. I voted to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @123 well... I have 2 examples with 2 quick answers that got it right so I guess someone found it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't match the general case, but works for your example:

```
awk '/^open|^close|^total/{print $2}' input
```

For the general case, if your definition of "string" is based on whitespace, perhaps you want:

```
tr -s ' \n' \\n < input | awk 'p{print; p=0} {p=/^open|^close|^total/}'
```

Comment: isn't $2 index specific? I don't necessarily know the location of the next word (index-wise), this is why I put the generic case with `string-*` and `match-*`. Notice how the match position differs

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk for printing next word after the search word:

```
awk -v s='^(open|close|total)$' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if ($i ~ s) print $(i+1)}' 

0.23
1.52
2.34
5.92
10.78
24.21
45.3
```